# The visual studio extension requires API v2 to be enabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, elmah.io

I installed elmah and I have got it fully working, however they also provide a visual studio extension - However when I try use it visual studio gives me an error saying:

"The Visual Studio Extension requires API V2 to be enabled"

Any ideas what that actually means, and what I need to do to "enable API V2" for visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API v2 can be enabled through the log settings view. The easiest approach is to navigate to the settings screen of the log you want to browse from the Visual Studio extension as described here: https://docs.elmah.io/where-is-my-log-id/. When on the log settings screen, click the *Actions* tab. On this tab, you can enable API v2.

We are planning a major overhaul of the VS extension which will allow for the extension to communicate with API v3 (the default containing improved security).

Comment: This is a setting in the elmah.io portal, not in visual studio like I first assumed.

Comment: For future reference, the elmah.io extension for Visual Studio now no longer requires the old API: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=elmahio.elmahio